# Are Mortal Kombat X for PC and android different games?

Tags: version-differences, mortal-kombat-x, mortal-kombat-x-mobile

I am playing Mortal Kombat X on Android, but feel that it has very few characters (only 56). I don't have it on PC and have never played it, but from youtube gameplay videos, it looks different. How different are these two versions? Do they have same battle modes, same characters?

Also, if I will purchase it from Steam, will I be able to link both my PC and Android game with same Warner Bros ID?

Comment: They are 100% separate

Answer (score 1):

They are completely separate games.

Yes, you can link your Mortal Kombat X PC game with your Android game. That is the way to get a few specific character skins for getting an achievement within the Android game.

Comment: So if I buy it on pc and log in by same id used on android, my already leveled up characters in android version will come in pc version too? Right

Comment: No, like I said, they are completely different games with different mechanics. The only thing that could happen is getting a few skins but that's it.